# Telerik Kendo MVC Grid - Setting Custom Filtering

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, telerik-grid, fluent

My company's product uses the Telerik MVC grid heavily (over 100 web pages with grids) and we're trying to find ways to minimize the amount of work needed to customize parts of these grids by setting those pieces from a class we've called Settings.

Here's an example of a grid.  You can see that we've successfully gotten this working with the .PageSize() and .Pageable(p.PageSizes()) settings.  However, the .Filterable(f.Operators()) is giving me trouble and I'm hoping that someone can point out what I'm doing wrong.

**GRID**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("grid")
    .DataSource(ds => ds
        .Ajax()
        .Filter(filter => filter.Add(group => group.Active).IsEqualTo(true))
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(m => m.Id);
            model.Field(m => m.Id).DefaultValue(new Guid());
        })
        .PageSize(Settings.DefaultPageSize)  //WORKING
        .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Users"))
        .Events(events => { events.Error("onDSErrors"); events.RequestEnd("onDSRequestEnd"); })
    )
    .Pageable(p => p
        .PageSizes(Settings.MvcGridPageSizes)  //WORKING
        .Refresh(true)
    )
    .Filterable(f => f
        .Extra(true)
        .Operators(Settings.MVCGridFilterOperators)  //NOT WORKING
    )
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(u => u.UserName)
            .Title("Username")
            .Width(200);
        ...
        ...
        ...
    })
)
```

**SETTINGS CLASS**
(*This is what I want to do and can't get working yet...*)

```
public static class Settings
{

    ...

    public static Action<FilterableOperatorsBuilder> MVCGridFilterOperators
    {
        get
        {
            FilterableOperators operators = new FilterableOperators();
            FilterableOperatorsBuilder builder = new FilterableOperatorsBuilder(operators);

            builder.ForString(x => x
                .Contains("Contains")
                .DoesNotContain("Does not contain")
                .StartsWith("Starts with")
                .EndsWith("Ends with")
                .IsEqualTo("Is equal to")
                .IsNotEqualTo("Is not equal to")
                .IsNull("Is null")
                .IsNotNull("Is not null")
            );

            return builder;
            //Error message I see when hovering over "return builder;":
            //   Cannot implicitly convert type ‘Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.FilterableOperatorsBuilder’ to ‘System.Action<Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.FilterableOperatorsBuilder>’
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

Currently the filterable operators section in all our grids has to be updated in each of the 100+ grids if any changes are requested because they look like this:

```
.Operators(o => o
    .ForString(str => str
        .Clear()
        .Contains("Contains")
        .DoesNotContain("Does not contain")
        .StartsWith("Starts with")
        .EndsWith("Ends with")
        .IsEqualTo("Is equal to")
        .IsNotEqualTo("Is not equal to")
    )
)
```

Since we use so many of the grids, updating them takes a while since it requires a copy/paste or find and replace for each grid. Thank you in advance for any help you can offer me!

Answer (score 0):

after some research, i discovered that this is possible and opens up a lot of possiblities for pre-setting settings on kendo mvc grids.  You need to create a class file similar to this:

```
public static class CustomGridHelperExtensions
{
    public static Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.GridBuilder<T> MyGrid<T>(this HtmlHelper helper)
        where T : class
    {
        return helper.Kendo().Grid<T>()
            .Filterable(filterable => filterable
                .Extra(true)   //This extended "filterable" section of code makes the contains filter the default string filter for these grids
                .Operators(operators => operators
                    .ForString(str => str
                        .Clear()
                        .Contains("Contains")
                        .DoesNotContain("Does not contain")
                        .StartsWith("Starts with")
                        .EndsWith("Ends with")
                        .IsEqualTo("Is equal to")
                        .IsNotEqualTo("Is not equal to")
                        .IsNull("Is null")
                        .IsNotNull("Is not null")
                    )
                )
            );
    }
```

then, instead of the normal way of setting up the grid, you do this instead

```
       @(Html.MyGrid<model>() 

                     .DataSource(ds => ds
                        .Ajax()
                        .Filter(filter => ...'
```

I hope this helps.  Note i got some of this info from telerek's forums.